# Android AlertDialog with AutoCompleteTextView and soft input

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog, autocompletetextview

I have a simple Xamarin.Android application that just displays an alert dialog with an AutoCompleteTextView

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        var arr = new string[] { "Test", "Other Item", "Test 2", "Item Test" };

        AutoCompleteTextView tv = new AutoCompleteTextView(this);
        tv.Threshold = 2;
        tv.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, arr);

        Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder d = new Android.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        d.SetView(tv);
        d.Create().Show();
    }
```

When it opens everytihing is fine...
[image: first image]

However when I start to type in and the autocomplete dropdown appears, the view gets shifted down as if the soft input was closed...

[image: second image]

And now the fun part, changing the package name from

`com.companyname.test_app` to

`com.companyname.test_app_1`

fixes it...

[image: third image]

What is causing this and how to fix it?

E1: Rewrote the code into Kotlin and deployed it. Android studio warned me that an app with the same pacakage name exists, do I want to uninstall? -> Yes. Launches but the same problem occurs.

E2: From the discussion below. I tried:

- Explicitly setting the soft input mode as an attribute.
- Explicitly setting the soft input mode in the Manifest.
- Setting in on the dialog `.Window` property
- On the `.Window` property of the Activity
- On dialog `.Window` as `Support.V7.App.AlertDialog`

E3: Running the same code in android emulator works... but that was expected.

E4: Tried CCleaner to remove all Mono runtimes and other packages that are added by Xamarin. Did not work.

E5: Tried FragmentDialog, did not do a thing...

E6: So I decided to reinvent the wheel...
`EditText` + `PopupWindow` but the popup window was rendering above the soft input method, for that I found that setting

`popupWindow.InputMethodMode = InputMethod.Needed;`

is causing it! A breakthough. Now why is this persistent in a package?

Comment: Usually you will be able to set something like this `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` in your MainActivity attribute or the AndroidManifest file that should fix this, which you already seem to have. But occasionally it doesn't (cache clearing), so you have to do the same programmatically inside your OnCreateView that you have above: `Dialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan);`

Comment: Added `Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan);` and `dialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(Android.Views.SoftInput.AdjustPan);` also tried the Support library AlertDialog. Added the attributes to MainActivity. Did not work. @Saamer

Comment: Try Dialog.Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustPan|SoftInput.AdjustResize);

Comment: Did not help either. I am concerned about the fact that changing the package name makes it work. Shouldn't uninstalling the app clear everything?

Comment: Hmm Did you try to place this as an attribute above your MainActivity, along with the other attributes? `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"`. Uninstalling the app should clear everything unless you have some custom code in the application. Try it with an absolutely new solution and see if you are able to replicate it. Also you can edit the soft input settings inside the layout file of your dialog

Comment: The thing is this code will work in new solution as long as I change the package name to something that has not been 'infected' by this. I can change the package name of the very first code and it will work. so the problem has to be somewhere else.

Comment: "Shouldn't uninstalling the app clear everything?" No, Visual Studio has its own cache that it uses in order to reduce the time it takes to build. You have to delete the bin and obj folders in your solution in order to delete the cache completely. The easy way is to do a `git clean -fxd` if you have a .gitignore properly set

Comment: This project is just an exctract of the main project, where I first encountered the problem. It does not have a proper `git` setup.  Manualy deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders in this test project did not help... When I found it in main i created this and set it up exactly as my main project, which includes the package name. (but before I uninstalled it from the android device)

Comment: The device you tested on may has already install an application with the package name `com.companyname.test_app`, that caused the issue. Try to check the application manager of the device to uninstall the app with the same package name. Or change the package name of current project. You could test the application on another device, it should work fine.

Comment: Ultimately I need to get the main app to work, and changing the package name is a hack that I want to avoid, what if the bug comes back in that package name as well, how many package names would I have to go thought till I find what is causing it?. And I did uninstall the app with the same package name as per 'E1'.

Comment: Package name is a unique identifier for a package and therefore you should not have the same package name for both the library and the application. To avoid using the same package name, make sure every project's name is different.

Comment: There is only one application. (one Android project).

Comment: The statement may be not very clear, sorry for that. I mean that each project you created to test on a deivce should has an unique package name.

Comment: Still how do I test something that only happens when the package name is exactly equal to "something" and works when you change it to "whatever"...

Comment: At usual, using the same package name will overwrite the previous version during testing. In your case, the two applications may come from different IDE(Android stuido and visual studio). And using an unique correct package name will not cause an issue.

Comment: I edited the main post, found what is causing it. But no idea why...

Comment: InputMethod.Needed: this popup always needs to work with an input method, regardless of whether it is focusable. Tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.widget.inputmethod?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9